# pm2 hibernates apps after a while

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, pm2

I have 2 apps running on a raspberry pi. One is an API the other one is a history tracker that writes every 6 hours to a database. I run these with PM2, but I think that it hibernates the apps after a while since I can't access them after a while.

pm2 commands used:

```
sudo pm2 start historytracker
sudo pm2 start app.js //api
sudo pm2 startup //apply this generated line
```

historytracker( i doubt the problem lies in here, it works on console in windows and on linux):

```
let j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 */6 * * *', function() {
    request('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);
            coinAmount = body.active_currencies;
            console.log(coinAmount);
            request('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=' + coinAmount, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    body = JSON.parse(body);
                    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
                        let sql = "INSERT INTO `tblCoinHistory`(`name`, `price_btc`) VALUES (?,?)";
                        if (body[i].name == "bitcoin") {
                            inserts = [body[i].name, body[i].price_usd];
                        } else {
                            inserts = [body[i].name, body[i].price_btc];
                        }
                        sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
                        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```